# How to use regular expression in prev()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to use regular expression in prev()?

```html
<div class="aaa">aaa</div>
<div style="display: none" class="bbb">bbb</div>
<div style="display: none" class="ccc">ccc</div>
<div class="ddd">ddd</div>
```

```javascript
$(".ddd").click(function(){
    alert($(this).prev('display:visible').attr('class'));
})
```

This not working. If i have:

This should show me "aaa". If i remove "display:  visible" from prev() then this show me "ccc".

http://jsfiddle.net/WaVrw/

Comment: How is this related to regular expressions?

Comment: Please, explain us what you are aiming, what is you prblem ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
$(".ddd").click(function(){
    alert($(this).prevAll(':visible:eq(0)').attr('class'));
})
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/WaVrw/3/)

[prevAll](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/) Get all preceding siblings of each element in the set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector.

[eq(0)](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) to get only the first element.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
$(".ddd").click(function(){
    alert($(this).prevAll("div:visible:eq(0)").attr("class"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
$(".ddd").click(function(){
    alert($(this).prev(':visible').attr('class'));
})
```

This uses the jQuery [:visible](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) selector to find elements that are visible.

Comment: `prev(selector)` does not find previous `selector`, it selects the previous sibling and returns it if it matches `selector`.